# SQL Server query dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this table `Table1`:

```
Room - StartDate - EndDate
1    - 01/01/2013  05/01/2013
1    - 14/01/2013  15/01/2013
2    - 10/01/2013  13/01/2013
```

I want to show all the available 'Rooms' from 02/01/2013 to 03/01/2013

I use:

```
select * 
from Table1 
where ('02/01/2013' NOT BETWEEN table1.stardate AND table1.enddate) 
   OR ('03/01/2013' NOT BETWEEN table1.startdate AND table1.enddate)
```

But the query result shows 2 (this is correct) **but also 1, because of the last record**.

What can I do to show only 'Room 2'?

thx

Comment: Table1 is booked rooms table or available rooms table?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you already have another table, for `Rooms`.

So, if `Table1` is a `Reservations` table:

```
SELECT  r.* 
FROM    Rooms AS r
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT    *
          FROM      Table1 AS res
          WHERE     res.Room = rooms.RoomID
            AND     '20120102' < res.EndDate 
            AND     res.StartDate < '20120103' 
        ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing that enddate is always > startdate, change `OR` to `AND`

```
select * 
from   Table1
where  ('02/01/2013' NOT BETWEEN table1.startdate AND table1.enddate)
AND    ('03/01/2013' NOT BETWEEN table1.startdate AND table1.enddate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from Table1 

where(stardate >='02/01/2013' and enddate <= '03/01/2013')
```